# Entity Framework could not load the data from many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I have Models named Contest,Problem and Judge
A judge has many Contest and a Contest has many Judge

[DataBase Diagram for Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrMMv.png)

But when I accessed judges list from database by contest Id it's not working

```
var existingJudge = this.unitOfWork.JudgeRepository.Get()
            .Where(r => r.Contest_Id.Contains(id) && r.Id == User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

I have tried this too

```
existingJudge = this.unitOfWork.ContestRepository.GetById(id).JudgeList;
```

Here id   means contest id

Comment: Is there an error message or your var is empty ?

Comment: No i have no error message just the model is empty

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
var existingJudge = this.unitOfWork.JudgeRepository.Get()
        .Where(r => r.Contests.Any(t => t.Id == id));
```

if `id` contains the right number, this should work.

Comment: Are you sure there is data with the id

Comment: Here is the contest repository https://github.com/lazyfahim/Tritron/blob/master/DAL/ContestRepository.cs and here is the generic repository  https://github.com/lazyfahim/Tritron/blob/master/DAL/Repository.cs

Answer (score 0):

Several things can be wrong.

Can you please share your class diagram or classes as well. Are you marking the linked object properties (i.e. judges) as virtual? Also Your table is using AspNetUser as name, have you mapped your judge object properly? I would like to see how you mapped your objects to the table name.

Comment: Sir I have linked as virtual also referenced with ID foreign key. But noting worked. Here is my models https://github.com/lazyfahim/Tritron/tree/master/Model                                      and here is my repositories https://github.com/lazyfahim/Tritron/tree/master/Contracts                             and here is my application Db context                                                          https://github.com/lazyfahim/Tritron/tree/master/DAL

Comment: In JudgeContests table you are using Judge_Id to link with AspNetUsers table. By convention it should be User_Id instead. Also in code you are using JudgeList_Id as foreign key. I think your naming convention is inconsistent. You should try using correct names consistently in your entity and in tables. First try with default naming conventions. I do not feel you are in need of customized names. Instead you are confusing yourself using different names.

Comment: thank you sir but in another solve someone is suggesting to bind two classes with a judgecontests class in code. and using fluent api. I am totally a newcomer in asp.net mvc5.

Comment: Another class is not needed, but you can use fluent API which is good to use. But your naming inconsistency is important to fix. It is even difficult to understand the relation due to that. You can read an example here: how such relation is made: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx